# Can one derive the Hessian as a composition $\nabla \circ \nabla$?

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

In our lecture on continuous optimization there is a lot of operator-overloading when it comes to the $\nabla$-operator.

I originally know it as the gradient that, for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ was defined like this:

$$\nabla f(x) := \pmatrix{\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_n}}$$

or written differently

$$\nabla f(x) := \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i}$$

where $e_i$ is the i-th unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Now my problem arises since we often write $\nabla^2 f$ and similarly we write $\nabla h$ for a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ where we mean the Hessian and the Jakobi Matrix respectively.

My point of confusion is the question whether we just use lazy notation that is not strictly accurate, or whether I fail to understand how this operator works.
By the definition above and the linearity of the derivate I would have

$$\nabla^2 f(x) = (\nabla \circ \nabla) f(x) = \nabla (\nabla f(x)) = \nabla \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \nabla \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i}$$

and since also $\frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ I should by the same logic get something like

$$\sum_{i=1}^n e_i \nabla \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n e_i \sum_{j=1}^n e_j \frac{\delta^2 f(x)}{\delta x_j \delta x_i}$$

To me this seems more like column vectors whose entries are themselves column vectors instead of the Hessian Matrix.

Edit: It has been pointed out here that what the $\nabla^2$ notation likely refers to the dyadic/outer product of the $\nabla$-'vector'. This begs the question though if this notation can be rigorously justified/derived i.e. whether one can show that
$(\nabla \circ \nabla)f = (\nabla \nabla^\top)f$

Comment: Your last expression is correct and can be written in matrix notation as
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\;\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}\right)\Big(e_ie_j^T\Big)
$$
but many (most?) books use a dyadic product, e.g.
$\;\big(e_ie_j^T\big)\to(e_i\otimes e_j).\,$ Note that $\big(e_ie_j^T\big)$ is a matrix with a $\tt1$ as the $(i,j)$ element and zeros elsewhere.

Comment: @greg Thanks, could you show the transition from my last expression to the one in matrix notation you gave in an answer? I understand they should be the same but can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

We usually mean the following by $\nabla^2$
$$ \nabla^2 = ( \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)$$

The twice composition of the gradient :$\nabla \circ \nabla$ operator actually has a different meaning of it's own when evaluated correctly on a scalar field. It relates to the matrix which transforms displacements in the input plane into how the gradient vector varies.

Comment: I don't try to factorize it. It is supposed to be the composition between two operators (as I understand nabla as an operator, not a vector). To illustrate the difference
$(fg)(x) = f(x) g(x) \neq f(g(x)) = (f \circ g) (x)$

There is some overloading of that notation here though so I don't blame you.

Comment: Seems like you need a dyadic product to make this work in the notation you are using. [see pg-20](http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see the del operator as
$$
\nabla = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_N}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and simply interpret the Hessian as the outer product
$$
\mathbf{H}=
\nabla \nabla^T
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbf{Hf}=
\nabla \nabla^Tf=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_N}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} &
\ldots &
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_N}
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1^2} &
\ldots &
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_N} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_N \partial x_1} &
\ldots &
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_N^2} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

**UPDATE**
Let us write
$\nabla^T f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \mathbf{e}_n^T$

Thus
$$\mathbf{Hf}
=\sum_n \nabla \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right) \mathbf{e}_n^T
=\sum_n 
\sum_m \frac{\partial}{\partial x_m}
\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} \right) 
\mathbf{e}_m
\mathbf{e}_n^T=
\sum_{m,n} 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_m \partial x_n} 
\mathbf{e}_m
\mathbf{e}_n^T
$$

Comment: So what you are saying is that essentially we are doing lazy notation that has no proper mathematical background?

The thing is that nabla as a vector does not make sense on its own. I think you are right that what is meant by $\nabla^2$ in this script is the outer/dyadic product but I can't make sense of it in a rigorous way. If the notation you wrote is meaningful then one should be able to derive it from the understanding of $\nabla$ as an operator i.e. a function. Can you bridge that gap?

Comment: See my update that hopefully suits your need.

Comment: So $\nabla \circ \nabla = \nabla \nabla^\top$?

Answer (score 0):

First, I see a typo in
$$\tag{1}
\nabla^2 f(x) = \nabla (\nabla f(x)) = \color{red}{\nabla}\sum_{i=1}^n e_i \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i}\,.
$$
I find it hard to understand the expression
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n e_i \nabla \frac{\delta f(x)}{\delta x_i}
$$
because (1) is the scalar product of the vector $\nabla$ and the vector $\nabla f(x)\,.$ This leads to
$$
\nabla^2f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x_i^2}f(x)=\Delta f(x)\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the typo correction, I fixed it in the question.

I understood the $\nabla$ operator as a linear operator in the sense of functional analysis. So to me it was $\nabla^2 = \nabla \circ \nabla$ i.e. the composition of two functions, not a scalar product. The result if you treat it like a scalar product is also not the Hessian. Also: scalar products are only defined between two elements from the same space.